# data.map is not a function when trying to fetch api from twitch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, twitch-api

I am building a simple fan made page for a streamer using felix twitch  api . 2 days now i cant get around with a problem im facing when trying to display fetched  data to front end . My code is as follows.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import axios from 'axios';
 
 
 export const Home = () => {
 
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   const [data, setData] = useState([])
 
   const client_id = "3fjsnq21qnimeiel9b773vwbhmjurk";
   const token = "5z79quc5s7z0qbiiqmalqd4ueh4lue";
   const url = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/clips?broadcaster_id=42365125"
 
   const requestOptions = {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {
       "client-id": client_id,
       Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
     },
   };
 
   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchData = async () =>{
       setLoading(true);
       try {
         const {data: response} = await axios.get(url,requestOptions);
         setData(response.data);
         console.log(response.data)
 
       } catch (error) {
         console.error(error.message);
       }
       setLoading(false);
     }
 
 
     fetchData();
     console.log(data);
   }, []);
 
 
 
 
     return (
       <div>
         hi
       {loading && <div>Loading</div>}
       {!loading && (
         <div>
           <h2>Doing stuff with data</h2>
           {data.map(item => (<span>{item.id}</span>))}
         </div>
       )}
       </div>
     );
   
 };
```

What I'm trying to do here is to create an array of the data twitch returns. Which in Cli mode returns an object and inside of it and array . Then with the function map to go trhough all videos of the streamer in order to display them in my front end. Thats the  console in chrome with the code above.

[Check chrome  console image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0yD1.png)

Comment: Make sure that the data is an array. Maybe data is a Json string as you use JSON.stringify() when set the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In API response there is no need to stringify the data which is set in setData state....
There is no need when use axios to stringify the data

```
useEffect(() => {
 const fetchData = async () =>{
   setLoading(true);
   try {
     const {data: response} = await axios.get(url,requestOptions);
     setData(response.data);
     console.log(response.data)

   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error.message);
   }
   setLoading(false);
 }

 fetchData();
 console.log(data);
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much.  Before using axios i was calling the api with fetch. I will paste correct code in case someone else wants to do the same.

Comment: please give up vote as well